# How to change the child of a sibling when hovering over a div

Tags: jquery, css, squarespace

I am a Rails developer normally but I made the mistake of agreeing to do some Squarespace customization work. I'm trying to build a hover mask effect where when the user hovers over the image a title appears and the image becomes opaque.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="outerdiv">
    <a class="image" href="http://google.com">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></img>
    </a>
    <div class="title">
        words
    </div>
</div>
```

I originally tried having the outer div change opacity on hover and trigger the text to show but with that method the text is underneath the mask effect like so: http://jsfiddle.net/kaxla/L05wLccd/ I'm relatively sure it is not possible to fix this with CSS because of the way the HTML is laid out. Am I wrong?

Now I'm thinking it has to be done with JQuery so I've got this:

Here is my CSS:

```
.title {
  position:absolute;
  margin-top: -165px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Here is my JS(JQuery):

```
$(".image").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo("slow", .2);
});

$(".image").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
});

$(".outerdiv").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).find(".title").show();
});

$(".outerdiv").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).find(".title").hide();
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kaxla/pmujh90c/

It is working except when I hover over the title the opaque effect goes away.

Assuming it can't be fixed with plain CSS, what JQuery code would I need to trigger the image to change opacity when the title div is hovered over?

Comment: The words are sitting on top of the image so when you hover it, you are mouseleaving the image.

Comment: Ok so I can just remove the mousleave image part and it works but then the opacity stays all the time. There's no way to make it change opacity based on some instances of mouseleave and not others is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the JQuery a bit like this that makes it to do what you are looking for:

```
$(".outerdiv").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).find(".title").show();
  $(this).find('.image').fadeTo("slow", .2);    
});

$(".outerdiv").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).find(".title").hide();
  $(this).find('.image').fadeTo("slow", 1);        
});
```

Here is the working version:http://jsfiddle.net/pmujh90c/3/

Comment: Oh jesus, I knew it was something stupid like the order I had things in. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

What you are wanting to achieve is possible with CSS using the current HTML structure.

**Caveats**:

- This will not work on touch only devices.
- IE 8 & 9 do not support CSS transitions, so the opacity will change instantly instead of fade.

Hey is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2t09j3og/3/)**.

The HMTL:

```
<div class="outerdiv">
    <a class="image" href="http://google.com">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></img>
    </a>
    <div class="title">
        words
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
.outerdiv {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.outerdiv img {
    transition: opacity .6s ease;
}
.title {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: -165px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0;
    /* uncomment the line below to also transition the text */
    /* transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out; */
}

.outerdiv:hover img {
    opacity: .2;
}
.outerdiv:hover .title {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Explanation:**

The reason we are able to achieve this is because we attach the `:hover` to the `.outerdiv`, thus when we hover over `.title`, we are still hovering over `.outerdiv`.

The problem that has still not been solved is that the link is now obscured by `.title`. The best solution for this would be to modify the markup so that `.title` is inside the link, then we could treat `a.image` as we have treated `.outerdiv` until now.

A hack that will work for all browsers, except IE 8-10, is to add `pointer-events: none;` to `.title`, which will allow the click event to pass through it to the link below.

Answer (score 0):

when the mouse hovers the title its taking the focus from the picture so calling the mouseleave function you need set the title so it cant gain focus and it will be good to go